# Table offset changing based on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

i have a huge table as follows(was not knowing how to display in small block. Sorry for that)

```
    <div class="label class_258" id="txtElt11291968306091dIi15v" y2="4925" y1="3625" x2="229" x1="69" lineid="lineid" tag="div" pos_rel="false" selectedindex="11" sectionname="NEC3.sc">
       <table class="MsoTableGrid class_258_0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="781" align="left" border="1">
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_0_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0" tag="p">SI.No.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_0_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_0_0_1_0_0_0">Name of Subject        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_0_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_0_0_2_0_0_0">Courses covered under Diploma Level        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_0_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_0_0_3_0_0_0" tag="p">Courses 
 covered under Degree Level        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_0_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_0_0_4_0_0_0">Courses covered 
 under P.G. Level        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_1_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_1_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 1.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_1_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_1_0_1_0_0_0">Textile Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_1_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_1_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Textile Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_1_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_1_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech/B.E        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_1_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_1_0_4_0_0_0">M.Tech(Computer 
 Science)        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_2_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_2_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 2.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_2_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_2_0_1_0_0_0">Computer Science 
 &amp; Engineering        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_2_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_2_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Computer Science &amp; Engineering. BCA,DCA,PGDCA        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_2_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_2_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech/B.E/M.Sc.(Computer 
 Science)        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_2_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_2_0_4_0_0_0">M.Tech/M.E        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr tag="tr">
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_3_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_3_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 3.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_3_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_3_0_1_0_0_0">Electronics        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" tag="td" class="class_258_0_0_0_3_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_3_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Electronics Engineering        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_3_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_3_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech/B.E/M.Sc.(Electronics)        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_3_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_3_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_4_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_4_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 4.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_4_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_4_0_1_0_0_0">Telecom &amp; Communication 
 Engg.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_4_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_4_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Telecom Engineering        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_4_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_4_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_4_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_4_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_5_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_5_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 5.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_5_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_5_0_1_0_0_0">Automobile 
 Engineering        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_5_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_5_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Automobile Engineering        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_5_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_5_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_5_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_5_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" tag="td" class="class_258_0_0_0_6_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 6.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_6_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_1_0_0_0">Hotel/Travel 
 &amp; Tourism Management        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_6_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_2_0_0_0">PG Diploma 
 in Travel &amp; Tourism Management( 1yr.)        </p>
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_2_0_1_0">Diploma in 
 Hotel Management(3 yrs.)        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_6_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_6_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_6_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" tag="td" class="class_258_0_0_0_7_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_7_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 7.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_7_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_7_0_1_0_0_0">Teaching of 
 Physically/Mentally Handicapped        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_7_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_7_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 teaching of Physically /Mentally Handicapped        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_7_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_7_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_7_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_7_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_8_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_8_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 8.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_8_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_8_0_1_0_0_0">Ceramic &amp; Glass 
 Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_8_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_8_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Glass &amp; or Ceramic Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_8_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_8_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_8_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_8_0_4_0_0_0">M.A. Physical 
 Education        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_9_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_9_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;        </span> 
 9.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_9_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_9_0_1_0_0_0">Physical Education 
 &amp; Sports        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_9_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_9_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Physical Education        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_9_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_9_0_3_0_0_0">B.A.Ed., P.G. 
 Diploma in Physical Education &amp; Sports        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_9_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_9_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_10_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_10_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 10.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_10_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_10_0_1_0_0_0">Fashion Technology 
 &amp; Design        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_10_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_10_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Fashion Technology &amp; Design        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_10_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_10_0_3_0_0_0">Degree in 
 Fashion Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_10_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_10_0_4_0_0_0">M.A.Foreign 
 Trade        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_11_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_11_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 11.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_11_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_11_0_1_0_0_0">Para-Medical 
 including General Nursing        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_11_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_11_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Pharmacy, General Nursing, Psychiatric Nursing        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_11_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_11_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_11_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_11_0_4_0_0_0">M.Tech.Forestry        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_12_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_12_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 12.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_12_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_12_0_1_0_0_0">Foreign Trade 
 Management        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_12_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_12_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Foreign Trade Management        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_12_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_12_0_3_0_0_0">Degree in 
 Foreign Trade Management        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_12_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_12_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_13_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_13_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 13.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_13_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_13_0_1_0_0_0">Forestry        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_13_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_13_0_2_0_0_0">B.Sc. (Forestry) 
 3 year course        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_13_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_13_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech(Forestry)/M.Sc.(Forestry)        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_13_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_13_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_14_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_14_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 14.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_14_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_14_0_1_0_0_0">Ecology &amp; 
 Environment        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_14_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_14_0_2_0_0_0">B.Sc. (Ecology 
 &amp; Environment) 3 yrs        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_14_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_14_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech/M.Sc        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_14_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_14_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_15_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_15_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 15.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_15_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_15_0_1_0_0_0">Gemmology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_15_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_15_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Gemmology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_15_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_15_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_15_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_15_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_16_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_16_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 16.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_16_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_16_0_1_0_0_0">Tea Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_16_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_16_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Tea Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_16_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_16_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_16_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_16_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_17_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_17_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 17.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_17_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_17_0_1_0_0_0">Leather Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_17_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_17_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Leather Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_17_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_17_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_17_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_17_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_18_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_18_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 18.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_18_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_18_0_1_0_0_0">Resin Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_18_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_18_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Resin Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_18_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_18_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_18_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_18_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_19_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_19_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 19.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_19_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_19_0_1_0_0_0">Plastic Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_19_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_19_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Plastic Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_19_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_19_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_19_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_19_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_20_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_20_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 20.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_20_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_20_0_1_0_0_0">Mass Communication        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_20_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_20_0_2_0_0_0">BA/B.Sc. in 
 Mass Communication        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_20_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_20_0_3_0_0_0">M.Sc./P.G 
 Diploma in Mass Communication &amp; Journalism        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_20_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_20_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_21_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_21_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 21.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_21_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_21_0_1_0_0_0">Interior Decoration        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_21_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_21_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Interior Decoration        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_21_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_21_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_21_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_21_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_22_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_22_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 22.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_22_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_22_0_1_0_0_0">Indian System 
 of Medicine        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_22_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_22_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Indian System of Medicine        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_22_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_22_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_22_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_22_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_23_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_23_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 23.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_23_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_23_0_1_0_0_0">Bio-Technology        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_23_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_23_0_2_0_0_0">Diploma in 
 Bio-Tech 3 years course        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_23_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_23_0_3_0_0_0">B.Tech(Bio-Tech) 
 M.Sc. (Bio-Tech)        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_23_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_23_0_4_0_0_0">M.Tech(Bio-Tech)        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0">
         <td valign="top" width="51" class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0_0_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_24_0_0_0_0_0">        <span>&nbsp;        </span> 
 24.        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="143" class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0_1_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_24_0_1_0_0_0">Business Management        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="119" class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0_2_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_24_0_2_0_0_0">BBA/BBM        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="255" class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0_3_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_24_0_3_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
         <td valign="top" width="213" class="class_258_0_0_0_24_0_4_0">
         <p class="MsoNormal class_258_0_0_0_24_0_4_0_0_0">Nil        </p>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </div>
```

its offset is changing based on IE/safari/chrome/FF 
i did

```
alert(document.getElementById('txtElt11291968306091dIi15v').offsetHeight);
```

any help?

Comment: Holy bad class names, Batman!

Comment: these are system generated class names..

Comment: i dont think i'll be getting any answers on this moderators pls delete this post..

Comment: that's not how SO works.  Also, give up and use conditional CSS.  Its the easiest way to fix your cross-browser css woes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`offsetHeight` returns the height of the visible area for an object, in pixels. So the differences you are seeing are probably due to different browsers having different sized viewing areas. What exactly is the problem this difference is causing?

Comment: hieght is coming to be 1300 in case of IE and 1376 in case of safari.. so it basically overlaps with other elements kept on page

Answer (score 0):

What offset are you talking about?

It could be the [Doubled Float-Margin Bug](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/doubled-margin.html)

Comment: updated my question.. couldnt understand anything from the link.. it seems for IE6/7 issue this issue is with Chrome and other browsers